# Memset to UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8> in swift

Tags: swift, pointers, allocation

I have a challenge with a variable with type `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>`.

I have this working code to alloc and set to zero all an `UInt8` array in Swift.
`var bits = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(calloc(width * height, 8))`

The problem is I'd like to do it without use the calloc method. I have this code to alloc the array
`var bits = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.alloc(width * height)`

but I can't find a method to set to zero all the memory.

I know I can do this, but I don't think is the best way.

```
for index in 0..< (width * height) {
    bits[index] = 0
}
```

Comment: "but I don't think is the best way" Sorry, can you clarify what's wrong with it? I mean, `calloc` must loop through the memory too, so what's the difference?

Comment: Nothing is wrong.  It works, but I am just looking a function like `memset` to initialize the array.  I googled it for a couple of hours and I searched in Stack overflow with no luck.  Right now I am using the `calloc` approach.

Comment: You could say `bits.initializeFrom(Array<UInt8>(count: width * height, repeatedValue: 0))` I suppose.

Comment: @matt. Yes, that is what I was looking for. It was easier than I thought.

Comment: Well, if you actually like it, I'll give it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could say:

```
bits.initializeFrom(Array<UInt8>(count: width * height, repeatedValue: 0))
```

I'm guessing there's some underlying efficiency to copying the memory this way. But of course there's an inefficiency in that we temporarily make the array. [NOTE: AirspeedVelocity's answer shows a way to avoid that.]

Personally, I liked your original loop best, especially if you write it more compactly, like this:

```
(0 ..< (width*height)).map {bits[$0] = 0}
```

Comment: Yes, it is not a `memset` but it is an alternative way.

Comment: I would have written your loop like this: `(0 ..< (width*height)).map {bits[$0] = 0}` Personally I like that way much better.

Comment: Instead of creating an array to do this just to throw it away again, you could use the `Repeat` sequence:  `bits.initializeFrom(Repeat(count: 100, repeatedValue: 0))`.

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity But is `Repeat` lazy? If not, I don't see the advantage. You'd still be creating a collection of `width*height` zeroes only to throw it away again.

Comment: @matt depends what you mean by lazy… it’s a collection type that with a start index of 0, an end index of `count`, and returns the same number every time.  Unlike an array, it won’t allocate a region of `count` entries in memory, it just takes the two parameters and stores them.  So it’s more efficient in theory than the array approach (though, chances are, with the optimizer, they’ll actually result in the same assembly code)

Comment: also, with both the `Repeat` and `Array` versions, you can leave the `<UInt8>` part to be inferred from context

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity Well that _is_ what I mean by lazy. I don't see how you _know_ this (e.g. how do you know it's not just an array behind the scenes?), but if you _do_ know it, I wish you'd give it as an answer, as that would certainly be better than my answer.

Comment: It’s an assumption on my part admittedly… but I would be amazed if this is not exactly how it is implemented (especially given that `startIndex` and `endIndex` are computed properties, the generator is `IndexingGenerator`, the `sizeof` shows no hidden extras above the two values)

Comment: @matt done :)  re the generator posing as a collection – there are definite benefits to `Repeat` being a collection.  For example,  `initializeFrom` requires one! Collections aren’t just for things backed by real things – `Range` for example is a collection in a similar style, it only has a start and an end, not anything else backing it.  Collections are whatever you need to do to adhere to `CollectionType` e.g. of finite length, calls to `SequenceType` should be repeatable etc.

Comment: @matt sorry, I never knew that there is expiration time of 5 years on StackOverflow for commenting and answering. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 11):

As @matt suggests, you can use `initializeFrom` to initialize the memory.  I would use the `Repeat` collection type for this, as it avoids any interim allocation:

```
var bits = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.alloc(width * height)
bits.initializeFrom(Repeat(count: width * height, repeatedValue: 0))
```

(note, there’s no need to give the type of the value to `Repeat`, it can be inferred from the type of `bits`)

If you find you do this a lot, it might be worth creating a `calloc`-like extension to `UnsafeMutablePointer`:

```
extension UnsafeMutablePointer {
    // version that takes any kind of type for initial value
    static func calloc(num: Int, initialValue: T) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<T> {
        let ptr = UnsafeMutablePointer<T>.alloc(num)
        ptr.initializeFrom(Repeat(count: num, repeatedValue: initialValue))
        return ptr
    }

    // convenience version for integer-literal-creatable types 
    // that initializes to zero of that type
    static func calloc<I: IntegerLiteralConvertible>
      (num: Int) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<I> {
        return UnsafeMutablePointer<I>.calloc(num, initialValue: 0)
    }
}

// creates 100 UInt8s initialized to 0
var bits = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.calloc(100)
```

Comment: Is this will be as optimised as c `calloc`?